# JavaFX: Coordinates of nodes are wrong for no obvious reason

Tags: java, javafx, graph, nodes

I'm trying to visualize a graph in JavaFX. The nodes shall be interactive. At the moment I have a VBox and place as many HBoxes into it as I need levels in my graph. All the HBoxes are set to position their childrens centered. The childrens represent the individual nodes and are Buttons.
The VBox itself is placed in a StackPane with a Canvas as another children of the StackPane.
This StackPane is then placed into the Scene.
I want to use the Canvas to draw the joining Edges between the nodes. To get The coordinates of the nodes i use:

```
System.out.println(button.localToScene(button.getBoundsInLocal().getMinX(),
button.getBoundsInLocal().getMinY()));
```

But no matter where the button is positioned, the resulting coordinate remains:

```
Point2D [x = 0.0, y = 108.0]
```

for all the buttons. Every single Button has apparently the same coordinate though it's displayed correctly!

Please help me, im quite desperate right now...

**Edit:**

Here is the minimal example that works:

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    HBox buttons = new HBox();
    TabPane tabs = new TabPane();
    buttons.getChildren().addAll(
            new Button("1"),
            new Button("2"),
            new Button("3"));
    tabs.getTabs().addAll(
            new TabBoxes("____A____"),
            new TabBoxes("____B____"),
            new TabBoxes("____C____")
    );
    root.getChildren().addAll(buttons, tabs);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

*TabBoxes.java*

```
public class TabBoxes extends Tab {
private VBox vBox = new VBox();
private ArrayList<HBox> hBoxes;
private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
private StackPane stack = new StackPane();
private static final int V_INIT_SPACING = 60;
private static final int V_SPACING = 60;
private static final int H_SPACING = 60;

TabBoxes(String s){
    super(s);
    this.setContent(stack);
    setClosable(false);
    stack.getChildren().add(canvas);
    stack.getChildren().add(vBox);
    canvas.setWidth(2000);
    canvas.setHeight(1080);
    hBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    vBox.setSpacing(V_SPACING);
    vBox.translateYProperty().set(V_INIT_SPACING);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        hBoxes.add(new HBox() {
            {
                setSpacing(H_SPACING);
                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            }
        });
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            hBoxes.get(i).getChildren().add(new Button(i + "||" + j){
                {
                    setPrefSize(100,60);
                    setOnAction(e-> System.out.println("My coordinates are: " + localToScene(getBoundsInLocal().getMinX(),getBoundsInLocal().getMinY())));
                }
            });
        }
    }
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBoxes);

}
}
```

Comment: This should work, it the `StackPane` is the root of the scene. Could you post a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: In particular, it's important when this code is called; it needs to be called after the button has been added to a scene and layout has taken place.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue in a minimal example which lead me to check my code once more. I do not know exactly why but apparently the method call that includes setting up the scene had to be completly finished before reading out the coordinates (though reading out the coordinates happened after setting up the layout inside the method). I ended up splitting those two things and now I first add the Buttons to the layout and after that I call another method to update the lines which works fine. Thanks for encouraging me to create a minimal example! Helps a lot to simplify sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

[`boundsInLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInLocalProperty--) are coordinates in the `Button`'s own coordinate system. It's not surprising, that these values are the same.
If you want to calculate the coordinates in the `Canvas` coordinate system, transform the coordinates to the `StackPane` coordinates and then transform the coordinates to the `Canvas` coordinates:

```
Node n = button;
Point2D p = new Point2D(button.getBoundsInLocal().getMinX(), button.getBoundsInLocal().getMinY());
while (n != stackPane) {
     p = n.localToParent(p);
     n = n.getParent();
}

p = canvas.parentToLocal(p);
```

Comment: Sorry, I failed in copying the interesting line of code. Before the coordinate is used I also use `localToScene` on the local coordinates. So in full it's:

    `button.localToScene(button.getBoundsInLocal().getMinX(), button.getBoundsInLocal().getMinY())`

As far as I understood, your while-loop iterates through the different coordinate systems until it reaches the top level. But `localToScene` should also give me the coordinates based on the Scene's coordinates system. Or do I miss something?